sequelize изменяет дату при присваивании, как исправить?
    const now = db.moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // 2024-06-13 21:47:39
    const test = await db.test.findOne({ where: { test_id: 1}}); 

    console.log(test.created_at) // 2024-06-13 21:47:39

    test.created_at = now; // 2024-06-13 18:47:39 - почему тут сейчас 18:47:39

Облазил уже всю документацию в sequelize, так и не нашёл решения этой проблемы,знаю что в sequelize можно настроить timezone: '+03:00' к примеру в настройках, но эта тема не решает эту проблему, она решает проблему уже в самой таблице, но не при присваивании
проблема в том что когда я изменяю дату и отправляю данные на фронт - эти данные не с верной датой, разница в 3 часа, хотя в бд - всё отлично если настроить timezone: '+03:00'
